# Checking for uppercase/lowercase/numbers with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Either I'm being really retarded here or its just the lack of sleep but why doesn't this work? If I use the "or" operator it works for each separate test but as soon as it change it to the "and" operator it stops working.

I'm trying to test the password input of a form to see if its contains lowercase, uppercase and at least 1 number of symbol. I'm having a lot of trouble with this so help would be lovely, here is the code I have.

```
var upperCase= new RegExp('[^A-Z]');
var lowerCase= new RegExp('[^a-z]');
var numbers = new RegExp('[^0-9]');

if(!$(this).val().match(upperCase) && !$(this).val().match(lowerCase) && !$(this).val().match(numbers))    
{
    $("#passwordErrorMsg").html("Your password must be between 6 and 20 characters. It must contain a mixture of upper and lower case letters, and at least one number or symbol.");
}
else
{
    $("#passwordErrorMsg").html("OK")
}
```

Answer (score 21):

All of your regular expressions are searching for anything *except* the ranges that you have provided.  So, [^A-Z] looks for anything but A-Z.

You are also negating each match.

You might try modifying your regular expression definitions by removing the ^, and then reversing your logic.  So,

```
var upperCase= new RegExp('[A-Z]');
var lowerCase= new RegExp('[a-z]');
var numbers = new RegExp('[0-9]');

if($(this).val().match(upperCase) && $(this).val().match(lowerCase) &&   $(this).val().match(numbers))  
{
    $("#passwordErrorMsg").html("OK")

}
else
{
    $("#passwordErrorMsg").html("Your password must be between 6 and 20 characters.     It must contain a mixture of upper and lower case letters, and at least one number or symbol.");
}
```

This might even be a bit more intuitive to read?

Comment: Perfect, that worked! Thanks very much. Also, I have to check another input field against invalid characters, what would the RegExp be for that? Like, the bit between the brackets?

Comment: new RegExp('[^abc]'); where a b and c are the characters you want to mark as invalid. Remember to escape special characters with a backslash. This is a good regex reference http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Comment: Why can not use `if( !$(this).val().match(upperCase) || !$(this).val().match(lowerCase)  || !$(this).val().match(numbers))  
{`

Answer (score 0):

```
var upperCase= new RegExp('[A-Z]');
var lowerCase= new RegExp('[a-z]');
var numbers = new RegExp('[0-9]');

if($(this).val().match(upperCase) && $(this).val().match(lowerCase) &&   $(this).val().match(numbers) && $(this).val().lenght>=6 && $(this).val()<=20)  
{
    $("#passwordErrorMsg").html("OK")

}
else
{
    $("#passwordErrorMsg").html("Your password must be between 6 and 20 characters.     It must contain a mixture of upper and lower case letters, and at least one number or symbol.");
}
```